# Viewing a django-cms page via the slug

Tags: python, django, django-cms

How do you view a published django-cms page using a path that incorporates the slug?

I installed django-cms without error, and I can view the default cms homepage just fine. I created and published a simple "About" page with the slug "about", but when I visit `http://localhost:8000/about/` I get a 404 error. I can see the page if I use the "View on site" button, but that takes me to `http://localhost:8000/?preview=1&language=en`, not the real published path.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the code, I discovered that django-cms doesn't actually expose pages via their slug unless they're created **UNDER** a home page. The code that looks up a page via their slug looks in the cms_title table, and it stores '' for the slug for any page that's not a child. Very unintuitive, but after I re-created the page under a "Home" page, I could then access it via the `/about/` page.

Answer (score 0):

you won't get access until you check the `published` in cms page list view in admin.
`View on site` help with a **preview** before page is published.

Comment: I did that. That has no effect. The published flag is checked but I still get the behavior I mention.